# Wrong temperature/humidity results using SHT11 ZIG001

Tags: contiki

I have an issue in contiki2.7 (I use InstantContiki) using Z1 motes and ZIGLET Z001 (temperature & humidity).
I tried the code “test-sht11.c” in the directory examples/z1 to get the temperature and the humidity but I have wrong results:

```
Rime started with address 227.15
MAC e3:0f:00:00:00:00:00:00 Contiki 2.7 started. Node id is set to 4067.
CSMA ContikiMAC, channel check rate 8 Hz, radio channel 26
Starting 'SHT11 test'
Temperature:   615 degrees Celsius
Rel. humidity: 2650%
Temperature:   615 degrees Celsius
Rel. humidity: 2650%
```

I saw that the I2c drivers had to be disabled (http://sourceforge.net/p/contiki/mailman/message/29682840/) but it still doesn’t work, I have the same results.

Code :

---

```
#include "contiki.h"
#include "dev/sht11.h"
#include <stdio.h>

PROCESS(test_sht11_process, "SHT11 test");
AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&test_sht11_process);

PROCESS_THREAD(test_sht11_process, ev, data)
{
  static struct etimer et;
  static unsigned rh;

  PROCESS_BEGIN();
  i2c_disable();
  sht11_init();

  for (etimer_set(&et, CLOCK_SECOND);; etimer_reset(&et)) {
    PROCESS_YIELD();
    printf("Temperature:   %u degrees Celsius\n",
    (unsigned) (-39.60 + 0.01 * sht11_temp()));
    rh = sht11_humidity();
    printf("Rel. humidity: %u%%\n",
    (unsigned) (-4 + 0.0405*rh - 2.8e-6*(rh*rh)));
  }

  PROCESS_END();
}
```

---

I'm quite sure it’s not a hardware problem (I tried with different ZIG001 and different Z1 motes).
Thank you for your help, I'm  desperate…
Jibus.

Answer (score 0):

The person in charge on the repository advised to use the SHT25 instead of the SHT11. Those are new files that may not exist if you're stuck on an old contiki, so you'll have to get them manually. If you switch to a newer release, you'll get them.

If you just drop the files (.c and .h) next to the old sht11 ones (without updating contiki), don't forget to add the sht25.c in the Makefile (after sht11.c).

To use the new version of sensing (see the new examples for Z1) :

```
PROCESS_THREAD(test_sht25_process, ev, data)
{
  int16_t temperature, humidity;

  PROCESS_BEGIN();
  SENSORS_ACTIVATE(sht25);

  while(1) {
    etimer_set(&et, CLOCK_SECOND);
    PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL(etimer_expired(&et));
    temperature = sht25.value(SHT25_VAL_TEMP);
    printf("Temperature %d.%d ºC\n", temperature / 100, temperature % 100);
    humidity = sht25.value(SHT25_VAL_HUM);
    printf("Humidity %d.%d %RH\n", humidity / 100, humidity % 100);
  }
  PROCESS_END();
}
```

Also don't use sht11 for Z1 built-in temperature sensor like me, only for the zigglet that's attached to it (doesn't apply to the OP but may help someone else) ...